# How can I return int date,month, year in a single method

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I have written a java program which will return date, month and year
(datatype int)

```
    import java.util.*;
    class DateTime {


    int day,month,year;


    GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();

    public DateTime () {

      public  int TimeT() {


            day = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            month = date.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            year = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                   // return day;
      }

  }
```

**I am really confuse how to return day, month and year.** 
I have to return it, so I can use it many times.

Comment: What does C++ have to do with this?

Comment: Return it as an array of type `int`

Comment: convert it to a string...?

Comment: Create a class, or use Joda Time.

Comment: Low level: result = year * 10000 + moth * 100 + day (mostly useless when it comes to calculating a difference in days)

Comment: In line with what @jhobbie said, you could easily return an integer array of format such as {day, month, year}

Comment: 11 answers... nice question....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I may see what you are trying to say. 'Braj' had the right idea in the code he offered. However, I am not sure if that fully answers your needs or not. I am unsure as to whether you want to return each value (day, month, year) separately, or all together using one method? I will try my best regardless.

Below I will show you the code for DateTime:

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

class DateTime {
    private int day, month, year;
    GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();

    public DateTime() {
        day = date.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        month = date.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1;
        year = date.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);
    }
    public DateTime(int day, int month, int year){
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }

    // Accessors ///
    public int getDay(){
        return day;
    }
    public int getMonth(){
        return month;
    }
    public int getYear(){
        return year;
    }

    // Mutators ///
    public int setDay(){
        return day;
    }
    public int setMonth(){
        return month;
    }
    public int setYear(){
        return year;
    }

    // String ///
    public String toString(){
        return getMonth() + "/" + getDay() + "/" + getYear();
    }
}
```

Now to explain.

I made the day, month, and year `private` to begin with and kept your default constructor practically the same except for one thing.

I added 1 to the month because months January - December are indexed at 0 - 11 rather than 1 - 12. This means your month wouldn't follow conventional means. I never knew something such as the `GregorianCalendar` existed in java's `import` libraries, so I was initially confused for a couple of seconds when I tested my code.

Moving on I made an additional constructor in case you ever wanted to input your own dates for whatever reason. If you do not plan on making separate `DateTime` objects to hold random dates, then this is completely unnecessary.

Afterwards I made several accessors - `getDay()`, `getMonth()`, `getYear()` - in case you ever needed to grab the specific aspect of the date.

To finish it off I made a toString() method to print out your `DateTime`'s day month and year all in one `String` in a conventional format.

If you don't want to change the individual aspects of the date (such as the day, the month, or the year) I'd recommend getting rid of the 'Mutators'. If you don't want to access the individual aspects of the date, then I'd recommend getting rid of the 'Accessors'.

NOW, if for some reason, you want to be able to edit and access the date's components inside your CLIENT, then you should not make the instances of `day`, `month`, and `year` `private`, but instead `public`.

Here is the code for the DateTime class that will allow you to change the values inside the CLIENT. (I don't recommend this. I suggest you get used to making accessors and mutators instead.) I decided to call it `DateTime2`:

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

class DateTime2 {
    public int day, month, year;
    GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();

    public DateTime2() {
        day = date.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        month = date.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1;
        year = date.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);
    }
    public DateTime2(int day, int month, int year){
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
    }
}
```

I left the second constructor in there in case you still want to make separate `DateTime2` objects with different dates...

And here if the client code that tests the two classes out, followed by the output:

CLIENT:

```
public class DateTime_CLIENT{
    public static void main(){
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();

        System.out.println("- DateTime -");
        System.out.println("Date: " + dt);
        System.out.println("Month: " + dt.getMonth());
        System.out.println("Day: " + dt.getDay());
        System.out.println("Year: " + dt.getYear() + "\n");

        DateTime2 dt2 = new DateTime2();

        System.out.println("- DateTime2 -");
        System.out.println("Date: " + dt2);
        System.out.println("Month: " + dt2.month);
        System.out.println("Day: " + dt2.day);
        System.out.println("Year: " + dt2.year + "\n");

        dt2.day = 400000;

        System.out.println("- DateTime2 - CHANGE FROM CLIENT");
        System.out.println("Date: " + dt2);
        System.out.println("Month: " + dt2.month);
        System.out.println("Day: " + dt2.day);
        System.out.print("Year: " + dt2.year);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
- DateTime -
Date: 7/16/2014
Month: 7
Day: 16
Year: 2014

- DateTime2 -
Date: 7/16/2014
Month: 7
Day: 16
Year: 2014

- DateTime2 - CHANGE FROM CLIENT
Date: 7/400000/2014
Month: 7
Day: 400000
Year: 2014
```

Hope this helped! ;D

Comment: You are really helpful . 
return ""+month + "/" + day + "/" + year; 
This is what I needed.

Comment: Ah, I had a feeling that's what you were looking for >u< Wasn't exactly sure though lol. It was a pleasure to help :D

Comment: OH YEAH! And in the future if you post code, it's actually really easy. You can just copy paste in the class(es) and then select it and click ctrl + k. It looks normal now, but before when I copied and pasted it to get a good look at it, i got pretty confused xD

Answer (score 3):

Define a type to encapsulate the three attributes, and change method return type to that class, like this:

```
public class YearMonthDay {
    private final year;
    private final month;
    private final day;
    public int getYear() {return year;}
    public int getMonth() {return month;}
    public int getDay() {return day;}
    public YearMonthDay(int y, int m, int d) {
        year = y;
        month = m;
        day = d;
    }
    // Consider overriding toString, and optionally hashCode and equals
}
```

Now you can change your class to return `YearMonthDay`:

```
public YearMonthDay TimeT(){
    return new YearMonthDay(
        date.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    ,   date.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    ,   date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    );
}
```

A caller can now obtain the `YearMonthDay` once, and then access its properties from multiple places.

Comment: Perhaps also Override `toString()` in `YearMonthDay`.

Answer (score 1):

Create different method for each one

```
public int getDay(Date date){
     return date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
}

public int getMonth(Date date){
     return date.get(Calendar.MONTH);
}


public int getYear(Date date){
     return date.get(Calendar.YEAR);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a class out of the three fields and return an object of this type.

Answer (score 1):

Java can't actually return multiple values with a method. However, you can have your method return a string with the necessary information, then parse the string. Alternatively, create a daymonthyear object with all of the necessary attributes and return the object.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `HashMap`:

```
public HashMap<String, Integer> TimeT() {
    HashMap<String, Integer> dateMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    dateMap.put("day",date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    dateMap.put("month",date.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    dateMap.put("year",date.get(Calendar.YEAR));

    return dateMap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## String In Standard Format, `ISO 8601`

If you want to return the date information as text, use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library or the new java.time package in Java 8 to convert a date-time value into a String using the format defined by the [ISO 8601 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Those two libraries use ISO 8601 format by default. Such as `2014-07-13T18:02:49+05:30`:

```
String output = DateTime.now().toString(); // YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS+-00:00:00 format.
```

But it is best to specify a desired time zone rather than rely implicitly on the JVM's default time zone.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
String output = DateTime.now( timeZone ).toString();
```

If you want just year, month, and date only, then use an alternate formatter rather than the default one. The following code produces a string like `2014-07-13`.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime now = DateTime.now( timeZone );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.date(); // YYYY-MM-DD formatter.
String output = formatter.print( now );
```

## Pass `DateTime` Object

If instead of a string, you want the number values communicated to another object, then just pass the Joda-Time `DateTime` object. The receiving object can call methods on the DateTime such as `getYear`, `getMonthOfYear`, and `getDayOfMonth`. As a bonus, the receiving object will have additional information in its hands such as time zone.

The other answers are correct for the general case: Create a class or use a Collection to communicate multiple values as Java can return only a single item from a method. But in the specific case of date-time values, it seems silly to invent a class when we already have such classes at our disposal.

## Avoid `java.Util.Date` and `.Calendar`

The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Using Joda-Time as a replacement is quite common. The new java.time package in Java 8 is another replacement, and was inspired by Joda-Time.

## LocalDate Class

Both Joda-Time and java.time offer a `LocalDate` class to represent the date-only without time-of-day and without time zone. You may want to use this class. Usually a date-time is better if doing any comparisons across time zones, as a day’s beginning and ending are defined by a time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Best case is make a class with members year, month and day, initialized in the method an returned.

If only and *int* have to be used you could merge the data with bit operations.

`year | (month << 16) | (day << 24)`

Don't known if it's valid java.

Reading would be:
`year = date & 0xffff;`
`month = (date >> 16) & 0xff;`
`day = (date >> 24) & 0xff;`

This is more common in native language.

Answer (score 0):

It saems like the Calendar class already has everything the OP requires. There is no need to place the returned values into a hashmap or array or anything else. In the OP code, there is no return statement, but he wants to be able to re-use the code. Below is a simple method that demonstrates what the Calendar class gives us. Any method that returns a Calendar object is giving us everything we need because we can pull out the required values using `get`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int day,month,year;
   GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
   day = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
   month = date.get(Calendar.MONTH);
   year = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);
   System.out.println("Day:" + day);
   System.out.println("month:" + month);
   System.out.println("year:" + year);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. Return either the `Date` object (it contains everything you need) or an ISO string corresponding to this date in order to rebuild it later.